# Virsh migrate fails with "process exited while connecting to monitor" error

Tags: nfs, virsh

I am trying to migrate a VM from one host to another with below command

```
 virsh migrate --live nodetwo qemu+ssh://192.168.1.33/system
```

nodetwo = VM name

But I am getting an error as

> error: internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor: 2015-10-25T04:37:24.489443Z qemu-kvm: -drive file=/home/nodetwo/nodetwo.qcow2,if=none,id=drive-virtio-disk0,format=qcow2: could not open disk image /home/nodetwo/nodetwo.qcow2: Could not open file: Permission denied

`/home/nodetwo/nodetwo.qcow2` file has 777 permission. 
`/etc/libvirt/qemu.conf` file has user = root & group = root

Still not sure why I am getting above error. Directory `/home/nodetwo` contains the image file on source host and it is mounted on target host using NFS. (Source host = host that contains the guest and target host = host on which I want to migrate the guest)

Please help.

Comment: Do you have `no_root_squash` in your NFS export?  If not, then the NFS server will treat root as user `nobody`.  You should probably be running libvirt, qemu, etc as `libvirt-qemu` (or similar, depending on your distro) rather than as root, anyway.

Comment: It didn't work. In NFS exports I have given (rw) access to other nodes (*) so even if its other user (libvirt-qemu) it should not have given error 'permission denied'.

Comment: You didn't answer my question - do you have `no_root_squash` in your NFS export?  If not, then the NFS server will treat root as user `nobody`.  This means that as well as read-write access to the file `/home/nodetwo/nodetwo.qcow2`, nobody also needs read and execute access to `/home` and `/home/nodetwo`.  BTW, setting perms to 777 or 666 in order to "solve" permissions problems is never a good idea.

Comment: @cas I added no_root_squash to NFS exports, `/home/nodetwo   *(rw,no_root_squash,async)`  but still the error persists

Comment: did you reload the nfs server after changing `/etc/exports`?

Comment: yes, I used `exportfs -r` also I restarted the nfs service

Comment: can you cd into `/home/nodetwo` on the target host?  if yes, can you then read the qcow2 file? try `file nodetwo.qcow2` or similar.   and do you have SELinux on the target host?  that's often configured to only allow qemu etc to read disk images from certain locations (like `/var/lib/libvirt/images`)

Comment: @cas thanks a lot, migration is successful. I used `setsebool -P virt_use_nfs 1` also added my host information in `/etc/hosts` file to avoid error `error: unable to connect to server at 'node3:49152': No route to host`